# chart select data: there are more items than can fit in the menu

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have time series data with at least 250 data points.  I graph the data with a Sheets Line Chart.  I'd like to add some data points with labels to the graph via the Add Select Data Point option.

Problem is that after so many data points, the drop down selection menu says "There are more items than can fit in the menu."

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding labels to individual datapoints this way, instead create an additional column alongside the source table for your chart with entries in the appropriate rows for those datapoints you wish to label, then include this additional column in the source range for your chart and add the labels by clicking the 'three dot' menu next to the series name in chart editor/setup, then selecting 'Add labels' and selecting the new column.